# Documentation of CSHTML/Razor Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, documentation

I'm working on documenting our Display and Editor Templates (and as an extensions, documenting all of our CSHTML would be beneficial). Having said that, I've never seen any methodology of documenting CSHTML Razor Views.

For example, I have this CSHTML EditorTemplate: `MoneyPicker.cshtml`

```
@model Decimal?
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<div class="money-picker" data-money-picker>
    <div class="form-control-wrapper">
        @Html.TextBox(
            "",
            ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue,
            new
            {
                type = "number",
                @class = "form-control money-control",
                placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark ?? ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayName
            } )
    </div>
</div>
```

I know it's not C#, but is there some way to add XML documentation (or equivalent):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Displays a text box wrapped with the money-picker wrappers, allowing javascript to show money buttons to pick the value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Model">A currency value</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// The input is a text box that has the type "number"
    /// </remarks>
```

Or if not, has anyone found some way to documenting editor/display templates that could be picked up by some sort of system similar to Asp.Net WebApi's api help page? Ideally, it would go even farther and start at the parent type and allow you to drill into each of that type's property editors, etc., but I'm just trying to start small first.

EDIT: As part of this, I would also love to generate examples of the templates without having to hard/manually code said examples, just to help clarify the idea I had in mind.

Comment: What do you mean with: "... without having to hard/manually code said examples..."? Do you want the documentation to be created automaticly? And what is "As part of this"?? Part of what?

Answer (score 1):

I have looked into this too, but I could not found any method for documentating a `View`, now I have just documented the Views in the `Controller`:

```
/// <summary>
/// This is an example of documentation for the View.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>This is what I am returning.</returns>
public ActionResult CreateNewUser()
{
    return View();
}
```

You can generate documentation for this with e.g. SandCastle (I perfer this) or GhostDoc.

---

Of couse you could write normal comments in your `View` for explantion too.

```
@* This is a comment *@
```

Answer (score 0):

this is work in progress, but it might help.

## Context

An MVC 5 application migrating to MVC Core with a lot of in-house developed HtmlHelpers that have to be rewritten from scratch for MVC Core [:-(] but, want to start using MVC Core right away, with as few view changes as possible.

The idea is to have a catalog of helpers, running as an MVC Core app, documenting Razor usage.

## Result

[image: Final catalog display]

## Solution

Creating a ViewComponent, that reads the current view's source and displays it as formatted html, along the actual html output.

Then just creating a partial view with a sample for each HtmlHelper, will do the trick.

In this case HtmlHelpers generate different html according to a "ViewRole" that states whether the view is in display or edit mode.

### Partial view

```
@model App.WebLib.AspNetCore.WebApp.Areas.AppHelpers.Models.AppHelpersViewModel

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelTagFor(m => m.TextInput, 4)
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @Html.TextTagFor(Model.ViewRole, m => m.TextInput)
    </div>
</div>

@await Component.InvokeAsync("DisplaySource", new { executingViewPath = ViewContext.ExecutingFilePath, viewRole = Model.ViewRole })
```

### Index View

```
@model App.WebLib.AspNetCore.WebApp.Areas.AppHelpers.Models.AppHelpersViewModel

@{
    var displayModel = Model.GetDisplayCopy();
}

<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <h3>Estructura General de las Formas</h3>
            @Html.Partial("_FormLayout")

            <h3>Helper Básicos</h3>

            <h4>Campo de texto</h4>
            @Html.Partial("_TextInput")
            @Html.Partial("_TextInput", displayModel)

            <h4>Campo numérico</h4>
            @Html.Partial("_NumberInput")
            @Html.Partial("_NumberInput", displayModel)
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

### Model

```
public class AppHelpersViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public AppHelpersViewModel()
    {
        ViewRole = ViewRole.Edit;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Text Display Name", Prompt = "Text Display Prompt")]
    public string TextInput { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Number Display Name")]
    public decimal NumberInput { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date Display Name")]
    public DateTime? DateInput { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Bool Display Name", Prompt ="Bool Display Prompt")]
    public bool BoolInput { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Required Text Input Label", Prompt = "Placeholder Text")]
    [Required]
    public string RequiredTextInput { get; set; }


    public AppHelpersViewModel GetDisplayCopy()
    {
        var displayCopy = this.MemberwiseClone() as AppHelpersViewModel;

        displayCopy.ViewRole = ViewRole.Display;

        displayCopy.TextInput = "TextInput content";
        displayCopy.RequiredTextInput = "RequiredTextInput content";
        displayCopy.NumberInput = 45.4m;
        displayCopy.DateInput = new DateTime(2016, 10, 24);
        displayCopy.BoolInput = true;

        return displayCopy;
    }
}
```

### ViewComponent

```
public class DisplaySourceViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public DisplaySourceViewComponent(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        WebRootPath = hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        ContentRootPath = hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
    }

    public string ContentRootPath { get; set; }

    public string WebRootPath { get; set; }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string executingViewPath, ViewRole viewRole)
    {
        if (viewRole != ViewRole.Display)
        {
            return new NullViewComponentResult();
        }

        IEnumerable<string> viewSource = await GetViewSourceAsync(executingViewPath);

        return View(viewSource);
    }

    private int GetLastContentIndex(List<string> lines)
    {
        for (int i = lines.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lines[i]))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetViewSourceAsync(string executingViewPath)
    {
        executingViewPath = executingViewPath.Substring(1).Replace('/', Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);

        string viewFilePath = Path.Combine(ContentRootPath, executingViewPath);

        var lines = new List<string>();

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(viewFilePath, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            string line;

            while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
            {
                if (line.StartsWith("@model")) continue;
                if (line.StartsWith("@await") && line.Contains(@"InvokeAsync(""DisplaySource""")) continue;

                lines.Add(line);
            }
        }

        return Trim(lines);
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> Trim(List<string> lines)
    {
        var contentLines = new List<string>();

        int lastContentIndex = GetLastContentIndex(lines);

        for (int i = 0; i <= lastContentIndex; i++)
        {
            string line = lines[i];

            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) && contentLines.Count == 0) continue;

            contentLines.Add(line);
        }

        return contentLines;
    }
}

public class NullViewComponentResult : IViewComponentResult
{
    public void Execute(ViewComponentContext context)
    {
        return;
    }

    public Task ExecuteAsync(ViewComponentContext context)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

## TODOs

- Change ViewComponent usage to new (as of MVC Core 1.1) TagHelpers
  sintax.
- Include Model documentation in a similar way.
- Document a bunch of HtmlHelpers [that's mine! ;-)]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks you. I'm currently not upgrading our MVC5 project (which I just finished upgrading from MVC4) to Core, so I can't use the exact pattern, but what you've shown makes since. I'll see if there's a way to implement a similar methodology in MVC5.

Comment: @JamesHaug I guess you should be able to create a helper, instead of the ViewComponent to achieve just that. The key part is using  ViewContext.RouteData from the HtmlHelper and use some conventions to find the actual filepath to the partial view and then just read the file.

Comment: Actually, now that I write this I realize I should be able to take the ViewContext from the HtmlHelper, without having to pass it as a parameter.